# Как запустить функцию при смене роутера vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, router

Использую роутер vue.js 2.0
При переходе по ссылке mysite/id1 идёт загрузка данных пользователя с id1.
Мне нужно сделать, что б когда роутер меняется на значения  mysite/id:id , то должна сработать функция.
Я делаю так

```
var routes = [ 
    {
        path: '/id:id', component: UserPage, name: "UserPage",
        beforeEnter :(to, from, next) => {
            console.log(to);
            GM.UserPage.GetUserInfo(to.params.id);
            next();
        } 
    }.......
```

Но `beforeEnter` срабатывает, только, если я был на другом роуте(тоесть, например на странице `mysite/info`), но если я был внутри роута,т.е на странице   `mysite/id1` и хочу перейти на `mysite/id2` бто эта ф-я не срабатыват. А `beforeEach`  тоже не работает.
Можно глобально прописать при изменении всего роута `beforeEach`, но если у меня куча компонентов, то получается, через case отлавливать и прописывать? или как реализовать эту задачу?

Answer (score 3):

Можно передать параметры маршрута в качестве входных данных компоненту.
Для этого свойству `props` в маршруте указываем значение `true`.

```
var routes = [ 
  {
      path: '/id:id', 
      component: UserPage, 
      name: "UserPage",
      props: true
  }
]
```

и указываем входные параметры в компоненте

```
const UserPage = {
  props: ['id'],
  // ...
}
```

[Подробнее о передачи входных параметров в компоненты](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/essentials/passing-props.html).

Если нужно выполнить какую-то логику после изменения `id`, 
можно использовать [вычисляемые свойства или `watch`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).
В вашем случае подойдет `watch`

```
const UserPage = {
  props: ['id'],
  watch: {
    // эта функция запускается при изменении id
    id: function (id) {
      GM.UserPage.GetUserInfo(id);
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

---

Другой способ использовать сторожевой хук [`beforeRouteUpdate`](https://router.vuejs.org/ru/advanced/navigation-guards.html) непосредственно в компоненте.

> Вызывается когда маршрут, что рендерит этот компонент изменился,
>   но этот компонент будет повторно использован в новом маршруте.
>   Например, для маршрута с динамическими параметрами /foo/:id, когда мы
>   перемещаемся между /foo/1 и /foo/2, экземпляр того же компонента Foo
>   будет использован повторно, и этот хук будет вызван когда это случится.
>   Также имеется доступ в `this` к экземпляру компонента.

```
const UserPage = {
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    GM.UserPage.GetUserInfo(to.params.id);
    next();
  }
}
```

---

Еще способ отслеживать маршрут в компоненте

```
const UserPage = {
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      GM.UserPage.GetUserInfo(to.params.id);
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```